# Statistics of Black Holes

Tags: cosmology, black-holes

I am hoping to collect information about the sampling distribution of black hole sizes, densities, and their relative spatial distribution within galaxies and other formations. By sampling distributions I simply mean the empirical distributions for the black holes that have been observed to date.

How big is our current sample? Do these distributions have any major [modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics))? Is there any significant and unexplained bias, skew or variability in these distributions that is inconsistent with current models of black hole formation?

Comment: Are you considering supermassive black holes in your search, or do you want only stellar-mass black holes?

Comment: Thanks @KyleKanos We can certainly place them in a separate category for this question.

Comment: Note that any count is likely to be an undercount, since only black holes with a binary companion close enough to accrete matter, or close enough to resolve the binary partner and the reduced mass of the orbit will be visible by current methods.

Comment: Thanks @JerrySchirmer but I suppose we can still make an educated guess?